# Get the offset of previous line in a file

Tags: java, file

I'm extracting data from a file line by line into a database and i can't figure out a proper way to flag lines that I've already read into my database.

I have the following code that I use to iterate through the file lines and I attempt to verify
that the line has my flag or else I try to append the flag to the file line

```
List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
File logFile = new File("C:\\MyStuff\\SyslogCatchAllCopy.txt");
try {
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(logFile, "rw");
  String line = "";
  String doneReadingFlag = "##";
  Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(logFile);
  while ((line = raf.readLine()) != null && !line.contains(doneReading)) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
    String temp = "";
    if (!s.hasNext(doneReadingFlag)) {
      fileLines.add(line);
      raf.write(doneReadingFlag.getBytes(), (int) raf.getFilePointer(),
          doneReadingFlag.getBytes().length);
    } else {
      System.err.println("Allready Red");
    }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found" + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Exception while reading the file ");
}
// return fileLines;
// MoreProccessing(fileLines);
```

This code appends the flag to the next line and it overwrites the characters in that position
Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

When you write to a file, it doesn't insert do you should expect it to replace the characters.

You need to reserve space in the file for information you want to change or you can add information to another file.

Or instead of marking each file, you can store somewhere the lines number (or better the character position) you have read up to.

If you are not restarting your process you can have process read the file as it is appended (meaning you might not need to store where you are up to anywhere)

Comment: I have no problem replacing the characters, the problem is the replaced characters are of the next line not the line I'm reading in the current iteration of the while loop 
All I need to get the offset of the line that I'm reading inside the loop

Comment: according to my process once I read the line into the DB I can remove it from the file or skip reading it

Comment: In that case take the offset *before* you read the line. If you use this offset you will be overwriting the start of the line. (Rather than the characters after the line just read)

Comment: I tried to do so as well, and I always get an error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Native Method)

Comment: Normally this would only happen if you tried to access before the start of the file. Are you using the actual position or are you trying to calculate it?

Comment: you've been a great help :) I did that and it worked for me 
Thanks man ... YOU ROCK !

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Lawrey I did as you said and it worked for me like that:

as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> fileLines=new ArrayList<String>();
File logFile=new File("C:\\MyStuff\\MyFile.txt");

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(logFile, "rw");
String line="";
String doneReadingFlag="#";
long oldOffset=raf.getFilePointer();
long newOffset=oldOffset;

while ((line=raf.readLine())!=null)
{
     newOffset=raf.getFilePointer();    

     if(!line.contains(doneReadingFlag))
     {
           fileLines.add(line);
           raf.seek((long)oldOffset);
           raf.writeChars(doneReadingFlag);
           raf.seek(newOffset);
           System.out.println("Line added and flaged");
     }
     else
     {
           System.err.println("Already Red");
     }
     oldOffset=newOffset;
}
```